# Symmetry group of hypercube in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, geometry

Let $ T= \{(x, y, z, w) \in \mathbb{R}^4 \text{ }|\text{ }|x|,\, |y|,\,|z|,\,|w| \le 1\}$ be the hypercube in $\mathbb{R}^4$ of side length $2$ centered at the origin. Identify the symmetry group of $T$.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, it is a worthwhile exercise to identify the set $H$ of hyperfaces $($which are cubes of side length $2)$ and verify that $|H| = 8$.

Choose any hyperface of $T$. This hyperface can be taken to any of the $8$ hyperfaces of $T$, and then transformed via the symmetry group of a cube, which has order $48$. Doing this fixes a symmetry of the entire hypercube, so $|\text{Aut}(T)| = 8(48) = 384$.

---

In the interests of completeness, we now answer a more a general question, Exercise M.4 from Chapter 6 of Artin's *Algebra*.

> With coordinates $x_1, \dots, x_n$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ as usual, the set of points defined by the inequalities $-1 \le x_i \le +1$, for $i = 1, \dots, n$, is an $n$-dimensional *hypercube* $\mathcal{C}_n$. The $1$-dimensional hypercube is a line segment and the $2$-dimensional hypercube is a square. The $4$-dimensional hypercube has eight *face cubes*, the $3$-dimensional cubes defined by $\{x_i = 1\}$ and by $\{x_i = -1\}$, for $i = 1, 2, 3, 4$, and it has $16$ *vertices* $(\pm1,\pm1,\pm1,\pm1)$.
>
> Let $G_n$ denote the subgroup of the orthogonal group $O_n$ of elements that send the hypercube to itself, the group of symmetries of $\mathcal{C}_n$, including the orientation-reversing symmetries. Permutations of the coordinates and sign changes are among the elements of $G_n$.
>
> 1. Use the counting formula and induction to determine the order of the group $G_n$.
> 2. Describe $G_n$ explicitly, and identify the stabilizer of the vertex $(1, \dots, 1)$. Check your answer by showing that $G_2$ is isomorphic to the dihedral group $D_4$.

**Lemma.** Let $A\in O_n$ be an orthogonal matrix $($$AA^\text{T} = A^\text{T} A = I_n$$)$ and $A_1, \dots,A_n$ be the rows of $A$. Then $A\in G_n$ if and only if $A$ sends the *set of vertices* $(\pm1, \dots,\pm1)$ of the hypercube to itself.

*Proof.* If $A\in G_n$, then for a fixed choice of signs $\epsilon_1,\dots,\epsilon_n\in\{-1,1\}$, $f(x) = (\epsilon_1,\ldots,\epsilon_n)Ax^\text{T}$ $(x\in\mathcal{C}_n)$, a continuous real function over the compact set $\mathcal{C}_n$, is maximized at some boundary point $($vertex$)$ $v = (\epsilon'_1,\ldots,\epsilon'_n)\in\{-1,1\}^n$. But we know $f$ has maximum $\sum \epsilon_i^2 = n$ attained only when $Ax^\text{T} = (\epsilon_1,\ldots,\epsilon_n)^\text{T}$, so $Av^\text{T} = Ax^\text{T}\implies v=x=(\epsilon_1,\ldots,\epsilon_n)A$. Thus every vertex $(\epsilon_1,\ldots,\epsilon_n)^\text{T}$ of $A$ can be *uniquely* expressed as $Av^\text{T}$ for some vertex $v$, so by a counting argument each vertex must occur exactly once, and $A$ fixes the set of vertices of $\mathcal{C}_n$.

Conversely, suppose $A$ fixed the set of vertices of $\mathcal{C}_n$. If we label the vertex $v_1,\ldots,v_{2^n}$, then a point $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ lies in $\mathcal{C}_n$ if and only if it can be written in the form $\lambda_1v_1+\dots+\lambda_{2^n}v_{2^n}$ for some nonnegative weights $\lambda_i$ summing up to $1$. It follows that a point $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ lies in $A\mathcal{C}_n$ if and only if it can be written in the form $\sum \lambda_i (Av_i^\text{T})$. But the $Av_i^\text{T}$ are simply a permutation of the $v_i$, so $A\mathcal{C}_n = \mathcal{C}_n$, as desired. $\square$

Now take $A\in G_n$ with rows $A_1,\ldots,A_n$. Then $A_i\cdot (\epsilon_1,\ldots,\epsilon_n) = \pm1$ for $\epsilon_i=\pm1$. But then $A_i\cdot(-\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\ldots,\epsilon_n)=\pm1$ as well, so subtracting yields $a_{i1} = A_i\cdot(1,0,\ldots,0) \in\{-1,0,1\}$. By symmetry, $A\in\{-1,0,1\}^{n\times n}$. Now if $A_i\in\mathcal{C}_n$, so $-1\le A_i\cdot A_i\le 1$, whence $A_i$ has at most $1$ nonzero term. But it cannot have all zeros $($otherwise $A_i\cdot(1,\ldots,1)$ would vanish$)$, so it must have exactly $1$ term equal to $\pm1$, and everything else equal to $0$. Let this $\pm1$ term be at index $k_i$. Then $k_i\ne k_j$ when $i\ne j$, or else $Ax^\text{T}$ will have equal $i$ and $j$ coordinates for all $x$ $($and we certainly cannot hit all of $\mathcal{C}_n$$)$. It follows that $k_1,\ldots,k_n$ is a permutation of $1,2,\ldots,n$.

Conversely, if $A$ has $\epsilon_i = \pm1$'s at entries $(i,\pi(i))$ $($for a fixed permutation $\pi\in S_n$$)$ and $0$'s elsewhere, then clearly $AA^\text{T} = I_n$ and $A\mathcal{C}_n = \mathcal{C}_n$: $A$ simply flips the sign of the $i$th coordinate by $\epsilon_i$ for every $i$, and afterwards permutes the coordinates according to $j\to\pi(j)$.

### 1.

By part $(2)$, $|G_n| = n!2^n$ $($$n!$ choices for $\pi$ and then $2$ for each $t_i)$.

We can also do this using induction, as suggested: instead let $G_n$ act on the set of *hyperfaces* $[-1,1]^{i-1}\times\{\epsilon_i\}\times[-1,1]^{n-i}$, for some $1\le i\le n$ and $\epsilon_i=\pm1$. Then the stabilizer of $[-1,1]^{n-1}\times\{+1\}$ is the subset of $G_n$ fixing the $n$th coordinate, which is isomorphic to $G_{n-1}$ $($in terms of our matrix $A$, we have row $n$ and column $n$ empty except for a $+1$ at $(n,n)$, and the upper left $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ matrix lies in $G_{n-1}$$)$, and the orbit is the set of all $2n$ hyperfaces. So $|G_n| = 2n|G_{n-1}|$, and clearly $|G_1| = 2$, so by induction $|G_n| = 2^n n!$.

### 2.

Let $P_\pi$ denote the permutation matrix corresponding to a permutation $\pi$ $($$1$'s at $(i,\pi(i))$$)$, and $Z_i$ denote the diagonal matrix with a $-1$ at $(i,i)$ and $+1$'s at the other diagonal entries. By the previous discussion, $A\in G_n$ if and only if $A = P_\pi Z_1^{t_1} \dots Z_n^{t_n}$ for some permutation $\pi\in S_n$ and $t_1,\ldots,t_n\in\{0,1\}$. $($In other words, $G_n$ consists of the matrices that can be obtained from permutation matrices by changing signs.$)$

Then $A(1,\ldots,1)^\text{T} = \left((-1)^{t_1},\ldots,(-1)^{t_n}\right)^\text{T}$, so the stabilizer of $(1,\ldots,1)$ is the set of permutation matrices $P_\pi$.

For $n=2$, $G_n$ is generated by $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \cos\frac\pi2 & -\sin\frac\pi2 \\ \sin\frac\pi2 & \cos\frac\pi2 \end{pmatrix} \text{ and } \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix},$$ and thus isomorphic to the dihedral group $D_4$.

$($Indeed, one could have begun this entire question by working out the group explicitly in dimension $2$ to build some intuition. We know that the symmetries of a square from the dihedral group, but here we want the orthogonal matrices that correspond to the symmetries. They are the eight matrices$$\begin{pmatrix} \pm1 & 0 \\ 0 & \pm1 \end{pmatrix}\text{ and }\begin{pmatrix} 0 & \pm1 \\ \pm1 & 0 \end{pmatrix},$$which is, of course, the group $D_4$.$)$

Comment: It seems that you are evoking the counting formula in the second paragraph, but I don’t find the stabilizer of a hyperface that simple, we are not allowed to turn it (in the context of an n-dimensional space) «inside-out» while having it stay where it was, and yet such an operation, be it a reflection or a rotation through $\pi$ belongs well to the group of symmetries of the corresponding cube, i.e. when studied for itself in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$, such a transformation, in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$,  is allowed only if the hyperface is assigned a proper and *new* place among the 2n places.

Comment: Restricted to $\mathbb{R}^3$, it amounts to saying that the stabilizer of a face of the cube is not isomorphic to $D_4$, seen as the group of symmetries of a single square.

IMO it’s more promising if we study the behaviour of hyperface-pairs instead.

Answer (score 1):

Hypercube is dual to the hyperoctahedron, which has 4 diagonals. So, we are allowed to permute these diagonals and we also can flip any diagonal. Thus, obtain the so called *hyperoctahedral group* or *signed symmetric group* of degree 4. It is the wreath product of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ (the group of order 2) by $S_4$ (the symmetric group of degree 4).